# Routing table behaviour coupled with bound sockets - unexpected behaviour

Tags: ip, routing, sockets, network-interface, routing-table

### Problem

I am experiencing some rather odd behavior where a seemingly unrelated default gateway route is having unexpected side-effects. I managed to replicate this issue with a minimal example. The aim here is mostly educational and I stumbled upon this while experimenting with a more complex scenario. In short, I am managing to connect to a web server on *192.168.0.3* when I believe I should not.

My laptop is connected to my home network using WiFi (*192.168.0.0/24* network). The routing table is listed below:

```bash
kevin@kevin-UX305LA:~$ ip route
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlp2s0 proto dhcp metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp2s0 scope link metric 1000 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.210 metric 600
```

Both `curl 192.168.0.3` and `curl --interface wlp2s0 192.168.0.3` currently work and give the following response:

```html
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.25.2</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, I proceed to remove all the routes related to the *192.168.0.0/24* network such that the remaining routes are:

```bash
kevin@kevin-UX305LA:~$ sudo ip route del default via 192.168.0.1 
kevin@kevin-UX305LA:~$ sudo ip route del 192.168.0.0/24 
kevin@kevin-UX305LA:~$ ip route
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp2s0 scope link metric 1000 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
```

Additionally, `ip route get` with and without binding to an interface are shown below:

```bash
kevin@kevin-UX305LA:~$ ip route get 192.168.0.3
RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable
kevin@kevin-UX305LA:~$ ip route get oif wlp2s0 192.168.0.3
192.168.0.3 dev wlp2s0 src 192.168.0.210 uid 1000 
    cache
```

Running `curl 192.168.0.3` gives `curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server` and running `curl --interface wlp2s0 192.168.0.3` gives nothing (curl is blocked). Here's a snippet of what strace shows:

```bash
setsockopt(5, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, "wlp2s0\0", 7) = 0
connect(5, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(80), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.0.3")}, 16) = -1 EINPROGRESS (Operation now in progress)
```

This is fine and what I was expecting, i.e., laptop shouldn't be able to reach *192.168.0.3*.

Now here is the strange part. If I add a dummy default gateway (say the *docker0* interface via a random address) such that my routing table is as follows:

```bash
kevin@kevin-UX305LA:~$ sudo ip route add default via 172.17.0.2
kevin@kevin-UX305LA:~$ ip route
default via 172.17.0.2 dev docker0 linkdown 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp2s0 scope link metric 1000 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
```

Running `curl 192.168.0.3` fails but running `curl --interface wlp2s0 192.168.0.3` succeeds with the previous HTML reply.

```bash
kevin@kevin-UX305LA:~$ curl 192.168.0.3
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.0.3 port 80 after 3068 ms: No route to host

kevin@kevin-UX305LA:~$ ip route get 192.168.0.3
192.168.0.3 via 172.17.0.2 dev docker0 src 172.17.0.1 uid 1000 
    cache 

kevin@kevin-UX305LA:~$ curl --interface wlp2s0 192.168.0.3
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.25.2</center>
</body>
</html>

kevin@kevin-UX305LA:~$ ip route get oif wlp2s0 192.168.0.3
192.168.0.3 dev wlp2s0 src 192.168.0.210 uid 1000 
    cache
```

I researched about`SO_BINDTODEVICE` and [found out](https://mirrors.slackware.com/slackware/slackware-3.6/docs/linux-2.0.35/networking/so_bindtodevice.txt) that it still should be obeying the routing table. Why does the addition of a default gateway through a different interface via a random address make `curl --interface wlp2s0 192.168.0.3` succeed?

### Address Details

The following command lists the addresses associated with the interfaces. I have checked that after each command executed above, the result of this command is always the same.

```bash
kevin@kevin-UX305LA:~$ ip -br addr
lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8 ::1/128 
wlp2s0           UP             192.168.0.210/24 fe80::7a03:3420:b8b0:4db7/64 
docker0          DOWN           172.17.0.1/16
```

In summary *192.168.0.210* is this laptop, *192.168.0.3* is another machine on the network hosting a web server and *192.168.0.1* is the default gateway (my router).

### Environment

I am running Linux Mint. Here is some info.

```bash
kevin@kevin-UX305LA:~$ uname -a
Linux kevin-UX305LA 5.15.0-84-generic #93-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 5 17:16:10 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

kevin@kevin-UX305LA:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Linuxmint
Description:    Linux Mint 21.2
Release:    21.2
Codename:   victoria
```

Comment: Can you *also* provide `ip -br addr` after having deleted the routes (because there are more than one way to do that)? Details matter here.

Comment: Most certainly. I updated the post to include the commands I used to delete and add routes and provided the output of `ip -br addr`

Comment: Sorry, I was just adding a comment (I updated the post so that I can ask you this below):

If `ip route get oif wlp2s0 192.168.0.3` gives back the same route in both cases (please see updated post), why does `curl --interface wlp2s0 192.168.0.3` block when I remove the related 192.168.0.0/24 routes and then work when I add a bogus default route to 172.17.0.2?

Comment: Indeed there's something else to figure out.

Comment: While I made a mockup to reproduce the experiment, this wasn't a complete mockup: no Docker is running. I can only guess the presence of Docker and iptables rules it's adding can change the behavior. In my test, it works the same with or without the route through docker0. I won't be able to go further and hope someone else will provide the final explanation.

Comment: Does `curl --interface wlp2s0 192.168.0.3` always succeed in your case? This is useful information. Indeed Docker could be affecting this. I will try to disable it temporarily and check whether anything changes.

Comment: Yes it always succeeds. Disabling docker is not enough, unless you erase its firewall/nat rules and also do `rmmod br_netfilter`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148860/discussion-between-user1847927-and-a-b).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When binding to the interface, unless adequate routes are found on this interface and then reused (for their gateway), [the packet is always emitted to the interface even without proper route](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/net/ipv4/route.c?h=v6.1#n2763). So this only matters when there's no such default route already present.

Note: the lack of gateway can cause problems with layer 2 interfaces (eg: trying to reach 8.8.8.8 would send an ARP request for 8.8.8.8. It wouldn't cause problems with layer 3 interfaces such as IP tunnels which don't need a gateway at all. Since in this question the destination is in the LAN anyway and thus doesn't require a gateway, this doesn't cause problems either.

The effect of the `curl` commands can be verified by querying the kernel for its route outcome like below using `ip route get`:

```shell
$ ip route get 192.168.0.3
RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable
# ip route get oif wlp2s0 192.168.0.3
192.168.0.3 dev wlp2s0 src 192.168.0.210 uid 0 
    cache 
$ ip route get oif wlp2s0 8.8.8.8
8.8.8.8 dev wlp2s0 src 192.168.0.210 uid 1000 
    cache
```

which resolves fine to reach 192.168.0.3.

To prevent this, one can add a policy rule that will select an alternate route only when binding to the interface with the `oif` selector. Normally that would be used to provide a route with an adequate gateway to fix the problem described above with a lack of gateway, for example like this:

```
ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlp2s0 onlink table 1000
ip rule add oif wlp2s0 lookup table 1000
```

But for this precise case, the goal is to prevent such kind of route to exist, which is more difficult, because `oif wlp2s0` keeps only routes having `dev wlp2s0` in them: simply adding a *blackhole* or *unreachable* route can't also include `dev wlp2s0` so it will always get ignored. Instead this requires a bogus route that will make the final result fail. Choosing one own's address as a gateway is the same as choosing no gateway: won't work either. So this require to pick an arbitrary address in the LAN that is guaranteed to not exist (to prevent it to do an ICMP redirect should it also be a router). Let's assume 192.168.0.4 doesn't exist and will be reserved for this use:

```shell
# ip route add default via 192.168.0.4 onlink dev wlp2s0 table 1000
# ip rule add oif wlp2s0 lookup 1000
```

which now gets:

```shell
$ ip route get oif wlp2s0 192.168.0.3
192.168.0.3 via 192.168.0.4 dev wlp2s0 table 1000 src 192.168.0.210 uid 1000 
    cache
```

which will trigger an ARP request for 192.168.0.4 and fail ~ 3 seconds later (the standard ARP maximum delay for such attempt) with an `EHOSTUNREACH` (No route to host):

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.0.3 port 80 after 3071 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

Note that the arbitrary IP address doesn't even have to be within 192.168.0.0/24. This would have worked the same, as long as the ARP request fails in the end:

```
ip route add default via 192.0.2.2 onlink dev wlp2s0 table 1000
```

Note: the same trick wouldn't work with a layer 3 interface (eg: WireGuard or OpenVPN in tun mode) since there's no concept of gateway on it.

---

**UPDATE**

### Solving OP's problem

I didn't address before the problem OP had: connectivity was failing rather than succeeding, and that adding a default route elsewhere made the attempt work.

The reason is that for now only half the communication was checked: from host to server, which could successfully emit a packet, not return traffic from server to host which has not been considered.

It was also discovered (through chat) that OP is using these [`rp_filter`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.rst?h=v6.1#n1555) settings:

```shell
$ sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 2
$ sysctl net.ipv4.conf.wlp2s0.rp_filter
net.ipv4.conf.wlp2s0.rp_filter = 2
```

which sets `wlp2s0` interfaces into Loose Reverse Path Forwarding mode defined in [RFC 3704](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3704).

> 2.4.  [Loose Reverse Path Forwarding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3704#section-2.4)
>
> Loose Reverse Path Forwarding (Loose RPF) is algorithmically
> **similar    to [strict RPF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3704#section-2.2)**, but differs in that it checks only for the **existence of a route (even a default route**, if applicable),
> **not where the route points to**.

Reverse Path Forwarding (RPF) is checking the *reverse path*: the return traffic from server to host, is compatible with the "normal" path, ie the route from host to server.

So when there's a default route (which is the most common scenario) Loose RPF actually always succeeds. Without the presence of a default route nor any route to the target, it will fail. Forcing an interface always succeeds for outgoing traffic, but this doesn't change the reverse traffic received from server to host. The reception of such ingress traffic is independent of the fact that the egress traffic was forced to an interface and cannot account for such case. Again this can be checked with `ip route get` when there's no default route anywhere. Starting from OP's case without added rule:

```shell
# ip route get from 192.168.0.3 iif wlp2s0 to 192.168.0.210
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid cross-device link
```

`Invalid cross-device link` is the error chosen by the network stack to tell RPF failed: such path is invalid, meaning what should be the return traffic from the server. Having the implicit default selected when binding to an interface doesn't affect *ingress* traffic, so doesn't change this result: timeout (but not due to ARP, so not limited to 3s).

The same check with `rp_filter=0`:

```shell
# sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=0
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 0
# sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=0
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 0
# ip route get from 192.168.0.3 iif wlp2s0 to 192.168.0.210
local 192.168.0.210 from 192.168.0.3 dev lo table local 
    cache <local> iif wlp2s0
```

works fine since the check is not done anymore.

Else, reverting back to `rp_filter=2`, doing this:

```shell
# ip route add 192.168.0.3/32 via 172.17.0.2
# ip route get from 192.168.0.3 iif wlp2s0 to 192.168.0.210
local 192.168.0.210 from 192.168.0.3 dev lo table local 
    cache <local> iif wlp2s0
```

also makes it work.

Merely adding a *wrong* route for 192.168.0.3 makes it pass the algorithm for Loose RPF. Of course adding a default route would has the same effect: as long as there's a route for 192.168.0.3, the Loose RPF will pass.

So either disable the `rp_filter` check completely as done above, or have any route for 192.168.0.3 wherever it is, including a default route using an other interface.

Comment: With regards to this statement: "When binding to the interface, unless adequate routes are found on this interface and then reused, an implicit default route without gateway gets added on this interface when resolving routing outcome." While I can verify it is true using `ip route get oif wlp2s0 192.168.0.3`, is there any documentation about implicit default routes? I would like to read more about this

Comment: @user1847927 https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/net/ipv4/route.c?h=v6.1#n2763